# GoogleMapReact not displaying map or marker

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, google-maps-react

I'm trying to set up a Google Map into my ReactJS application. I found out about GoogleMapReact through npm https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-map-react . I have added all of the settings, but when ran, the following displays:

[image]

The marker is displaying the name properly, but the map itself will not load. There are no warnings or errors in the console. Am I using the wrong type of key?

My code is as follows:

```
class Breweries extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        error: null,
        isLoaded: false,
        items: []
    };      
}

componentDidMount(){
    fetch("https://api.openbrewerydb.org/breweries?by_city=pittsburgh&by_state=pennsylvania")
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(
        (result) => {
            this.setState({
                isLoaded: true,
                items: result
            });
        },
        (error) => {
            this.setState({
            isLoaded: true,
            error
        });
    });        
}

render() {
    const { error, isLoaded, items } = this.state;
    if (error) {
        return <div>Error: {error.message}</div>;
    } else if (!isLoaded) {
        return <div>Loading...</div>;
    } else {
        return (
        <ListGroup>
            {items.map(item => (
                <ListGroup.Item key={item.name}>
                    <ul>
                        <li>{item.name}</li>
                        <li>{item.brewery_type}</li>
                        <li>{item.street}, {item.city}, {item.state}</li>
                        <li><a href={item.website_url}>{item.website_url}</a></li>

                        <MiniMap latitude={item.latitude} longitude={item.longitude} name={item.name} />
                    </ul>
                </ListGroup.Item>
            ))}
        </ListGroup>
        );
    }
}
}

const MiniMap = ({ latitude, longitude, name }) => (
<div style={{height: '500px', width: '500px', position: 'relative'}}>
    <GoogleMapReact bootstrapURLKeys={{ key: "*/ my google js api key is here */" }}
        center={{ latitude, longitude }}
        centerAroundCurrentLocation={true}
        zoom={11}
        resetBoundsOnResize={true}>
        <AnyReactComponent
            lat={latitude}
            lng={longitude}
            text={name}
        />
    </GoogleMapReact>
</div>
);
```

EDIT: Adding screenshot of API Key

[image]

Comment: Can you please provide your full code or a codesandbox/stackblitz so that we can reproduce this from our side? Your code without dependencies works fine on my end, even without a key your map should load with an error message instead of showing up completely blank and without errors, but in any case please double check your key is [valid](https://developers.google.com/maps/gmp-get-started#procedures).

Comment: That's just it, though. As you said, without a key, the map renders but with errors. They key should be valid, I will post a screenshot.

Comment: Does Google's JS API example map load with your own project's API key? Please test it, and also please share your full code so that we're able to reproduce this on our end.